# Problema ao enviar model para controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

Estou com problema pra encaminhar o meu model para o controle:

Class:

```
    public class Pessoa {
        public virtual long Id {get; set;}
        public virtual string Nome {get; set;}
        public virtual ETipo Tipo {get; set;}

        public virtual List ListaClientes {get; set;}
    }
```

View:

```
    @using Projeto.Model.Enum
    @model projeto.Model.Cadastro.Pessoa
    @{
        title = ".."

        List lstCliente = Model.ListaClientes;
    }

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SalvaPessoa", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"})) {

        @Html.Hidden(m => m.Id)
        @Html.Hidden(m => m.Nome)
        @Html.Hidden(m => m.Tipo)

        @foreach(var x in @lstCliente){

            Cliente
            @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.ListaClientes.IsAtivo, new{ class = "form"})

        }

        Salvar

        

        
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult SalvaPessoa(Pessoa model){
        ...
    }
```

Então, todos os campos estão chegando certinho no meu 
método do SalvaPessoa(), exceto a minha lista cuja foi
alterado o bool IsAtivo dentro do form;

Todos os campos estão valorizados, ate mesmo a lista 
ja vem do meu ActionResult() Valorizada.

Alguem pode me ajudar em como fazer para que essa minha lista
seja enviada junto para o SalvaPessoa()?

Comment: Da maneira que está fazendo, o form enviará um array de bool para o controller.

Comment: Como eu teria que fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Esse link me ajudou a fazer uma implementação que envia uma model com uma lista para o controller. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O correto seria:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    public virtual long Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Nome {get; set;}
    public virtual ETipo Tipo {get; set;}

    public virtual List<Cliente> ListaClientes {get; set;}
}
```

Outra coisa é montar o formulário com o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SalvaPessoa", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"})) {

    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Id)
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Nome)
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Tipo)

    @foreach(var x in @lstCliente)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Cliente", x)
    }

}
```

### `_Cliente.cshtml`

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Cliente

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaClientes"))
{
    Cliente
    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.IsAtivo, new { @class = "form"})
}
```

Feito isso, o *bind* no *Controller* aparecerá correto.

Comment: Passei conforme explicado, mas a lista continua chegando `null`

Comment: Estava pensando, será que apos fazer isso, nao teria alguma forma de aplicar minha `ListaClientes` para o model na minha View? Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Se você fez tudo certo, o MVC faz isso automaticamente. Se alguma coisa faltou, você receberá a lista nula.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certinho agora, eu realmente estava passando a lista errada `lstCliente` por isso não dava certo. Substituí pela `ListaClientes` e agora funcionando perfeitamente... @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 3):

Você pode por todas propriedades do cliente com a tag html `<input type="hidden"/>`

```
int index=0;

@foreach (var x in @lstCliente)
{
    //Cliente
    <input type="hidden" name="ListaClientes[@index].Nome" value="@x.Nome" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ListaClientes[@index].Documento" value="@x.Documento" />

    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.ListaClientes.IsAtivo, new { class = "form"})
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione uma propriedade List no objeto Pessoa. Assim quando renderizado o objeto chegar ao controle com suas informações.

No controller adicione um novo parâmetro para receber sua lista.

```
public JsonResult SalvaPessoa(Pessoa model, List<Pessoa> Pessoas){
    ...
}
```

E na View dentro das tags de form monte a lista que será enviada.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvaPessoa", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Id)
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Nome)
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Tipo)

    @for(int i = 0; i < lstCliente.Count; i++){

        Cliente
        @Html.CheckboxFor(m => Model.Pessoas[i].IsAtivo);
        ...
    }

    Salvar
}
```

Lembrando que os objetos da lista serão montados apenas com as informações que foram construídas dentro do for, no seu caso apenas o "isAtivo".

Para mais informações da uma olhada nesse link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET